# iphone grabkit library trouble in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone

[image]I am developing one iOS application in which I wan to integrate grabkit (excellent ) library.

I have tried to use in xocode 6 with 64 bit architecture but it shows me lots of error.

I have followed below instructions but still getting error
https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit

Can you please advice me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: post error screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, You forget to add some frameworks, which mentioned on install and configure process. 
Follow this two links,

install : [github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit/wiki/How-to-install-GrabKit](https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit/wiki/How-to-install-GrabKit)

configure : [github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit/wiki/How-to-configure-GrabKit](https://github.com/pierrotsmnrd/grabKit/wiki/How-to-configure-GrabKit)

Comment: I have added all frameworks and checked it...but getting same error.

Comment: Have you added linker flags ?

Comment: Yes I have added these flags -all_load,-ObjC,-lxml2

Answer (score 0):

Grabkit was build in 32bit XCODE..and now days as per apple rules iOS application must be build in 64bits else application get rejected. If we are trying to setup 32bit grabkit project in 64bits xcode then it got error. So now days we dont have to use Grabkit in any other project till the compatible version will be launch because of compatibility issue.